# Create variables and assign values via loop (bash)

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Is there a way to create bash variables and assign them values via a loop?

Something along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=0
for file in $( ls ); do
    var"$c"="$file";
    let c=$c+1;
done
```

EDIT: Thank you to @Costas and @mdpc for pointing out this would be a poor alternative to a list; the question is theoretical only.

Comment: NOTE: Be aware that your setup will  change/modify/assign variables only in the current process and NOT the  parent process if you execute this as a command.  You could source the file using the '.' command (EX: . new_vars) to make this happen within the current process.

Comment: Ok, but the above doesn't work actually run; `var"$c"` breaks it. @Costas 's answer demonstrates how to assign multiple values to a single list variable - I'm just asking theoretically whether variables can actually be _generated_ with a loop.

Comment: Hmmm...why so complicated, just using a new variable creates it without any fanfare.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, you absolutely can using **eval** as follows:

```
c=0
for file in $( ls ); do
    eval "var$c=$file";
    c=$((c+1));
done
```

This code will create variables named var0, var1, var2, ... with each one holding the file name. I assume you will have a good reason you want to do that over using an array ...

Answer (score 8):

Possible you mean array. There are some ways to assign values

#### First:

```
c=0
for file in $( ls ); do
    var[$c]="$file";
    c=$(($c+1));
done
```

#### Second:

```
c=0
for file in $( ls ); do
    var[c++]="$file";
done
```

#### Third:

```
for file in $( ls ); do
    var[${#var}]="$file";
done
```

#### Fourth:

```
var=( $(ls) )
```

#### Fifth

...

1. *there is no need to use `ls` , just put `*` for all files*
2. *inside `[]` the `$` sign can be ommited*

Comment: Thank you; my question is potentially more theoretical than actually practical. However,  when I `echo $var` with the commands you list above I only get the first file 'listed' by `ls`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you wants to output all array you have to use `echo ${var[*]}` (or `${var[@]}`), single element can be called like `echo ${var[1]}`. Note: `$var` is equal `${var[0]}`

Comment: @py4on Other way is use a loop: `for v in "${var[@]}";do echo $v;done`